# MySQL 5.7 RAND() and IF() without LIMIT leads to unexpected results

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
SELECT t.res, IF(t.res=0, "zero", "more than zero")
FROM (
SELECT table.*, IF (RAND()<=0.2,1, IF (RAND()<=0.4,2, IF (RAND()<=0.6,3,0))) AS res
FROM table LIMIT 20) t
```

which returns something like this:

[image: result with LIMIT]

That's exactly what you would expect. However, as soon as I remove the `LIMIT 20` I receive highly unexpected results (there are more rows returned than 20, I cut it off to make it easier to read):

```
SELECT t.res, IF(t.res=0, "zero", "more than zero")
FROM (
SELECT table.*, IF (RAND()<=0.2,1, IF (RAND()<=0.4,2, IF (RAND()<=0.6,3,0))) AS res
FROM table) t
```

[image: result without LIMIT]

*Side notes:*
I'm using MySQL 5.7.18-15-log and this is a highly abstracted example (real query is much more difficult).
**I'm trying to understand what is happening. I do not need answers that offer work arounds without any explanations why the original version is not working. Thank you.**

*Update:*
Instead of using `LIMIT`, `GROUP BY id` also works in the first case.

*Update 2:*
As requested by zerkms, I added `t.res = 0` and `t.res + 1` to the second example
[image: result without LIMIT and two more columns]

Comment: To reproduce, does your 'table' have exactly 20 rows, as it appears from your result set?

Comment: no, it has more rows

Comment: _Update:_ Instead of using `LIMIT`, `GROUP BY id` also works in the first case.

Comment: It's really hard to believe the second query produces that result set.

Comment: I find it odd that your second result set, without the limit, only shows 20 rows.  I grabbed a random table that I have that has 28 rows and tried your exact query, substituting my table name, and both worked as expected, with the second result containing 28 rows.

Comment: second example shows more rows. I just cut it off here to shorten my question. Sorry for the confusion. I'll add a note in the question

Comment: @SteveBrandli what MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Version 5.5.58.

Comment: Can you add 2 more columns to the second result set: `t.res = 0` and `t.res + 1`?

Comment: @zerkms updated the question. please check. even weirder...

Comment: WAAAAAAAAAT o_O

Comment: It looks like mysql recalculates the `t.res` value every time it sees it, to me it sounds like a bug. A possible solution (an ugly workaround): make a double nested query. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT table.*, ...)`

Comment: I think it is a bug because I recently upgraded to 5.7.x and I didn't have that problem with 5.6.x (but it's also possible I just never noticed)

Comment: Unfortunately, there are some bugs around `rand()` introduced with some optimization in mysql 5.7. Have a look at e.g. [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44336391/6248528). It looks like this is the same thing: MySQL knows `t.res` is a random value, and evaluates it again (with a different outcome) instead of using it from the subquery. `limit` creates a materlizes subquery, which is why it works as expected in teh first query (and making `limit 200000000` a a workaround)

Comment: Maybe try using RAND(1) instead of RAND() which returns the same random value for each call per entity. (https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-rand-function.php)

Comment: @pBuch that does not work unfortunately

Comment: @Solarflare your link leads to the solution. The `LIMIT` workaround is also mentioned there. Thanks

Comment: @Horen how about double nesting the query?

Comment: @zerkms I also tried that and it did not help. I think I'll go with the `GROUP BY id` solution for now

Comment: Thanks everyone, if someone wants to collect some rep, feel free to post the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by a change introduced in MySQL 5.7 on how derived tables in (sub)queries are treated.
Basically, in order to optimize performance, some subqueries are executed at different times and / or multiple times leading to unexpected results when your subquery returns non-deterministic results (like in my case with `RAND()`).
There are two easy (and likewise ugly) workarounds to get MySQL to "materialize" (aka return deterministic results) these subqueries: Use `LIMIT <high number>` or `GROUP BY id` both of which force MySQL to materialize the subquery and return the expected results.
The last option is turn off `derived_merge` in the `optimizer_switch` variable: `derived_merge=off` (make sure to leave all the other parameters as they are).

Further readings:
https://mysqlserverteam.com/derived-tables-in-mysql-5-7/
[Subquery's rand() column re-evaluated for every repeated selection in MySQL 5.7/8.0 vs MySQL 5.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336391/subquerys-rand-column-re-evaluated-for-every-repeated-selection-in-mysql-5-7)